# Linq query across 2 datasets while using String.Split

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to check if an entity exists using certain filters. This is what I started with

```
            bool jff = (from fm in dc.FamilyMembers
                    from f in dc.FamilyInfos
                    where fm.Family_ID == f.Family_ID && (fm.Last_Name == item.LastName && fm.Birthdate == item.DOB && f.Address1.Split(' ')[0].Contains(addNumber))
                    select new { fm, f }).Any();
```

Then I used AsEnumberable

```
        bool jff = (from fm in dc.FamilyMembers.AsEnumberable()
                    from f in dc.FamilyInfos.AsEnumberable()
                    where fm.Family_ID == f.Family_ID && (fm.Last_Name == item.LastName && fm.Birthdate == item.DOB && f.Address1.Split(' ')[0].Contains(addNumber))
                    select new { fm, f }).Any();
```

It took 3 mins, so I'm guessing this isn't the best way. Can anyone give any suggestions?

Comment: What type is `dc.FamilyMembers`? What variable is `item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well best way is to do this in the database instead of loading all into memory. Howeverer, a join and a pre-filter should be much more efficient:

```
var relevantFamilies = dc.FamilyMembers
    .Where(fm => fm.Last_Name == item.LastName && fm.Birthdate == item.DOB);

var relevantFamilyInfo = 
    from fm in relevantFamilies
    join fi in dc.FamilyInfos on fm.Family_ID equals fi.Family_ID
    select fi;

bool result = relevantFamilyInfo.AsEnumerable() // because you store multiple informations in Address1 you need to execute part of the query in memory, normalize your DB
    .Any(info => info.Address1.Split(' ')[0].Contains(addNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

EF Core has not translation for `Split`, but you can emulate first element retrieval:

```cs
bool jff = (
    from fm in dc.FamilyMembers
    from f in dc.FamilyInfos
    where fm.Family_ID == f.Family_ID && fm.Last_Name == item.LastName && fm.Birthdate == item.DOB 
        && f.Address1.Substring(0, f.Address1.IndexOf(" ")).Contains(addNumber)
    select new { fm, f }
    ).Any();
```